# Get multiple results from entity reference relationship in views

Tags: entities, views

In a view that displays content of a type that uses an Entity Reference (specifically User reference), I add that relationship but even though multiple users may be/are referenced by the content I only get one of them. Am I missing some sort of configuration?

In the relationship description: "A bridge to the User entity that is referenced via field_users"

EDIT: So after a private discussion with @Anil Sagar it seems that you cannot -using entityreference alone- display multiple results of the referenced entities in one row of the Entity the view displays.

The best you can get is:

Article One
body
image
user1 name
user1 surname

Article One
body
image
user2name
user2surname

(users 1 and 2 are referenced by Article One).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions would be either to use views_field_view and have an inner view that fetches all the referenced users by using article nid as a contextual filter,

or, using realname module to display first and last name wherever the username would be shown and remove the reference and add the users as a plain field (but that excludes any other fields that you may wanted to display) .

Answer (score 0):

- Verify Distinct Checkbox in View Query Settings. You should disable it.
- Verify number of items to display is more than one.
- Make sure no filters or contextual filters added that will effect the view results.

I just added a entity reference field to Article Content Type. And then added a relationship to the entity in view using Relationships. It does show multiple values.

I am not sure what other configurations are enabled in your view. See below query generated using views for above scenario.

SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, users_field_data_field_user.name AS users_field_data_field_user_name, users_field_data_field_user.uid AS users_field_data_field_user_uid, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_user} field_data_field_user ON node.nid = field_data_field_user.entity_id AND (field_data_field_user.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_user.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {users} users_field_data_field_user ON field_data_field_user.field_user_target_id = users_field_data_field_user.uid
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

Comment: "Verify number of items to display is more than one." Where do I find the setting you are refering to?

Comment: @magtak Under Pager settings you can see that...

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. I meant that the Entity Reference _field_ has multiple values. Of course I get all the results of the primary content type in my view. What I don't get is all the Entities' fields being referenced by each content.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Entity Reference field that has multiple values.

* I added a user entity reference field.
* For node one i selected 4 users
* For node two i selected 2 users
* I see total 6 results in my view.

Comment: Is your view fetching Users or Articles?

Comment: My View is fetching Articles..... But i disabled all Article related fields and added only user related fields.. So i see only user related content...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4799/discussion-between-anil-sagar-and-magtak)

Comment: So for each article you are getting all the referenced users. Can you try just for the sake of it to add an article related field? As in [artile title <user1, user2, user3, user4>]. (Brackets represent a row)